# Xcode 5 Delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I started to learn Objective-C and am doing the exercises according to a book, which is primarily aimed for Xcode 4. The book, Big Nerd Ranch Guide iOS Programming 4th edition, says that the application-Method is being automatically generated. In Xcode 5 there is no Code after the commentary

> // Override point for customization after application launch

So the

> lines self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
>
> [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

are missing. Is it normal or are there any settings to change?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  
    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question is not specific to XCode5. it depends on how you are creating your views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if you're using storyboards or not. With storyboards there will be no extra code in the AppDel. If you are creating a blank application and  doing it programatically then there will be.

Comment: Thank your very much. That was really helpful. I'm using a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This question is dated 27.01.2014 and I made my first attempts in writing any code for iOSDevelopment? (Which is obvious giving an example from the book Big Nerd Ranch Guide I'm working on). I don't know what people want to achieve by downvoting serious questions? Weren't you guys beginners before or does it feel good downgrading other people?

KR